# Error:Could not find exifinterface.jar (com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Well i was working on the project and it was doing all well but suddenly i am facing this error, it comes from no where i am not using any exitinterface library in my code.

the gradle build is as

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kpitb.manxoor.firebaseblog"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
 }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//    compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1"

compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the build error

```
 Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not find exifinterface.jar (com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/exifinterface/27.1.1/exifinterface-27.1.1.jar

Comment: did you add `allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}` ?

Comment: not working. and i have already     maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }.

Answer (score 1):

Well thats weird, i sloved this by swaping jcenter() with maven

before

```
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {                                  // <-- Add this
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven"
    }

}
```

And the Error was gone After

```
 repositories {

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {                                  // <-- Add this
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven"
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem:

**compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1"**

just change the exifinterface version for the supportLibVersion = "26.1.0", something like this :

**compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.1.0'**

and bum shakalaka !!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Yesterday everything was fine, today the error.
Adding `compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1"` result in `Could not find exifinterface.jar`.
So none of the solutions above work for me.

Regards, Alex.

Comment: check android.support libraries, make sure that you are using them with same level.    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Comment: I'm using api 27. I also tried changing this to 25, 26 or 28, of course changing the version of the used libraries accordingly. Stil the same error message stating `exifinterface` cannot be found.
I commented all code that used ExifInterface in my project (I can live without for a while) but even when `ExifInterface` is not used anywhere in my code, it stiil giving me this error.
So I remove the `.gradle` folder and the `workspace.xml`. Still the same error.

Comment: try invalidate and restart your android studio.

Comment: Just found why the error stille exists after removing all references to `ExifInterface`: I'm also using `Cropper` which uses `ExifInterface`...

Comment: Solved! I did put `google()` above `jcenter()` in the gradle files for my two modules, but not in the gradle file voor the project....
Thanks all!